# Mercurial - Get directory structure without cloning/operate on remote repository directly?

Tags: mercurial

I was wondering if there is any way to operate on a remote repository directly with mercurial?

I am building a Dreamweaver Mercurial plugin, and I would like to be able to list directories without having to clone the entire repository. Is this possible?

I tried using locate *, but when I use the command with hg it aborts with the message that the repository is not local, with local repositories of course it works.

Comment: Did you ever have success with creating your dreamweaver plugin for hg?

Comment: I did get a basic version functionally working. I may be able to find a copy of the source if you are interested. It was programmable in C#, with unmanaged C doing the communication with the dreamweaver API - I marshaled the unmanaged code into managed C# iirc. The other catch is the general plugin was an incomplete integration solution using a mysql redmine database to display a custom project tree with browsable repositories listed in this directory tree.

Comment: You had me up to the mysql part, I'm not sure whether I'd be able to apply enough resources to replace that or want to deal with running mysql (especially for a pure web designer to use)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That can't be done as part of the wire protocol, so you'll need to have a local repository. That said, there's relatively little you can do without a local repo in Mercurial, so it makes sense to require (probably even help the user have) a local repo.

Comment: One of the benefits of using a DVCS is the local repository, so I think cloning the whole repo is better anyway.